# Turn Bitlocker on with Powershell, Automating Device setup

Tags: windows, powershell, security, device, bitlocker

I have an issue that google has not yet given me a clear answer. our team sets up a range of laptops for staff to use and I have been working on a PowerShell script that will make our life easier. currently the script setups user accounts and installs the standard apps that they would use (Chrome, office, 7zip).

One task I have been looking at for the last few months is to turn on BitLocker. This is required by our IT policy and is needed on all devices that are removable from the site. We need to the script to do the following

- encrypt the C: drive.
- use the TPM chip and auto unlock windows.
- save a recovery key to a removable drive.
- we cant use AD or Group policy

I have tried a few different scripts and methods however the top contenders are:

```
Enable-BitLocker -EncryptionMethod Aes128 -MountPoint c: -UsedSpaceOnly -SkipHardwareTest -RecoveryKeyPath $RecoveryFolder -RecoveryKeyProtector
```

This appears to work however it saves the recovery key as a .BEK file.

I tried this one however this didn’t give me anything.

```
Enable-BitLocker -EncryptionMethod Aes128 -MountPoint c: -UsedSpaceOnly -SkipHardwareTest -RecoveryKeyPath $RecoveryFolder -RecoveryKeyProtector -RecoveryPassword -RecoveryPasswordProtector
```

I also tried using `Manage-bde` with the following:

```
manage-bde -on C: -recoverykey $RecoveryFolder -recoverypassword -UsedSpaceOnly
```

This gave me a .BEK file.

Ideally I would like a file that has the following content however if I just get the ID number and the Key then I could make the file up with this data though the script.

```
BitLocker Drive Encryption recovery key�

To verify that this is the correct recovery key, compare the start of the following identifier with the identifier value displayed on your PC.

Identifier:

    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

If the above identifier matches the one displayed by your PC then use the following key to unlock your drive.

Recovery Key:

    000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000

If the above identifier doesn't match the one displayed by your PC then this isn't the right key to unlock your drive.
Try another recovery key or refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=260589 for additional assistance.
```